# Eclipse Plugin Development Beginner

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

```
public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {

    // The plug-in ID
    public static final String PLUGIN_ID = "my.plugin.alps"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    // The shared instance
    private static Activator plugin;

    /**
     * The constructor
     */
    public Activator() {
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Activator.getDefault();
    }

    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        super.start(context);
        plugin = this;
    }


    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        plugin = null;
        super.stop(context);
    }

    public static Activator getDefault() {
        return plugin;
    }
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

    public static ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor(String path) {
        return imageDescriptorFromPlugin(PLUGIN_ID, path);
    }

}

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <category
            name="Sample Category"
            id="my.plugin.alps.commands.category">
      </category>
      <command
            name="Code Generator"
            categoryId="my.plugin.alps.commands.category"
            id="my.plugin.alps.commands.sampleCommand">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            commandId="my.plugin.alps.commands.sampleCommand"
            class="my.plugin.alps.handlers.SampleHandler">
      </handler>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key
            commandId="my.plugin.alps.commands.sampleCommand"
            contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
            sequence="M1+6"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration">
      </key>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
         <menu
               label="myLearning Portal for SAP (ALPS)"
               id="my.plugin.alps.menus.alps">
            <command
                  commandId="my.plugin.alps.generateCodes"
                  id="my.plugin.alps.menus.generateCodes"
                  label="Generate Codes"
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="my.plugin.alps.checkCodes"
                  id="my.plugin.alps.menus.checkCodes"
                  label="Check Codes"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
</plugin>

public class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
        MessageDialog.openInformation(
                window.getShell(),
                "Alps",
                "Use to generate codes");
        return null;



    }
}

I want it to be clickable and do something. I don't know where to add my source code for its function.
```

I am new to this kindly help me.
thank you very much.

1.I need it to be clickable ( it is greyed out when i run it )
2. I need to know where to add my code to have its functionality.
i.e when i click a menu, it will do something...
again,
    I have created my own plugin eclipse.
    I am new to this.
    How do i add functionality to the menus i created for my plugin?
    everytime i run it as eclipse application, the menu's are greyed out /cant be clicked.
    Maybe i missed out something?
    TIA!

Comment: See https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html

Comment: You don't have a `main` method in the plugin. Eclipse calls the other methods as and when needed.

Comment: @greg-449 so its impossible for this plugin to be runnable?

Comment: A plugin has to run as part of Eclipse. To test it you use 'Run as Eclipse Application' -  Eclipse starts a new instance of Eclipse which includes your plugin and has a separate workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the above code, there is a mismatch in the command ID specified.
Command ID should be same whenever you are trying to associate a command with a menu and it's handler. 
Try to provide the same command ID for Menu item and it's respective handler. 
Then the code would work fine.

Please find the modified plugin.xml below:

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
         <menu
               id="my.plugin.alps.menus.alps"
               label="myLearning Portal for SAP (ALPS)">
            <command
                  commandId="my.plugin.alps.generateCodes"
                  id="my.plugin.alps.menus.generateCodes"
                  label="Generate Codes"
                  style="push">
            </command>
            <command
                  commandId="my.plugin.alps.checkCodes"
                  id="my.plugin.alps.menus.checkCodes"
                  label="Check Codes"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
         <command
               id="my.plugin.alps.generateCodes"
               name="Generate Codes">
         </command>
         <command
               id="my.plugin.alps.checkCodes"
               name="Check Codes">
         </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            class="TestHandler"
            commandId="my.plugin.alps.generateCodes">
      </handler>
   </extension>
```